# How to automatically put email content on the webpage

Tags: php, email, web

I've been receiving a lot of spam emails and I want to post them on my website to serve as a warning for others not to believe it. Since I'm too lazy to login to my email account and check. I'm thinking to write a script in php (since this is the only one i know)that logs in to the mailbox at regular intervals, retrieves the content of the e-mails and then post it to my website automatically. Any suggestions on what would be the best approach to accomplish this task? Do I have to do PHP socket programming?

Thanks

Comment: The shared web hosting I signed up to they: Supported Incoming Mail Protocols: POP3, POP3S (SSL/TLS), IMAP, IMAPS (SSL/TLS)
Supported Outgoing Mail Protocols: SMTP, SMTPS (SSL/TLS)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your emails are filed under a Spam or Junk folder. You may want to set up a [Cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) that runs periodically to [read via IMAP or POP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).

You may want to check what're the protocols supported by your service provider and where exactly you want to post the information to - a database or HTTP POST.